# How To make 2 or more tables From one JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-table

I am working on creating dynamic HTML table from JSON Data, I have already created the table dynamically but now I have to Change it with new Requirement

**What I am doing**

- I have array of objects from which i am creating the table and spiting the table into four columns by dividing the length of JSON to 4
- My table is rendering perfectly into 4 columns

**What I am trying to Do**

- I want to show only 5 Rows in a single go then reloads the div and render the next five rows in same dive and so on until all data gets render
- Currently I have 68 total data so i am populating it as 17 rows of 4 columns
- Now on one go when page lodes I want to show 5 rows then after `5 seconds` Next 5 rows in same div
- In simple terms I want to split my JSON data into part of 5-5 rows and show only 5 rows at once then next five after `5 seconds`
- Spiting the Table into Four Columns I have done already,now just want to Show only five rows at a time
- I am lacking with idea or approach how to do this, How can i divide my JSON in five-five rows and show them at each time interval of 5 seconds

**What I am have done**

```js
var tableValue = [{
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
  "SellingPrice": 100
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANCHOW NV SOUP ",
  "SellingPrice": 125
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD V",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD NV",
  "SellingPrice": 230
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAMBUS REBOZADAS",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANCO FISH FINGER",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM DUPLEX",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "FRENCH FRIES",
  "SellingPrice": 99
}, {
  "Item Name": "HONEY GARLIC PRAWN",
  "SellingPrice": 350
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN MANCHURIAN",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "MUSHROOM CHILLY",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SALT N PEPPER BABY CORN",
  "SellingPrice": 120
}, {
  "Item Name": "SOUTHERN STYLE CHICKEN",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "PANEER NAGGETS",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARA BHARA KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA",
  "SellingPrice": 210
}, {
  "Item Name": "KALMI KEBAB",
  "SellingPrice": 250
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA MARGARITTA",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "PIZZA VEG FARMHOUSE",
  "SellingPrice": 200
}, {
  "Item Name": "BBQ CHICKEN PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA PIZZA",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "PESTO SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 175
}, {
  "Item Name": "ARABIATA",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "PINK SAUCE",
  "SellingPrice": 160
}, {
  "Item Name": "GARBANZO BEAN SALAD",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MASALA PAPAD",
  "SellingPrice": 50
}, {
  "Item Name": "PEANUT MASALA",
  "SellingPrice": 60
}, {
  "Item Name": "GAJAR KA HALWA",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "WATERMELON MARTINI",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Kiwi martini",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": " Apple gin",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber  cooler ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Martini",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pink lady",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": " Bloody marry",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cosmopolitan",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Sex on the beach",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Bull frog",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "Long  island iced tea ",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "Pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Daiquiri",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mojito ",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Whisky sour",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "Hot toddy",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "Margarita",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Tequila sunrise",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "Red sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "White sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rose sangria",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "By chance special ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Made in heaven",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Strawberry delight",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "DRAGON",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Mangochil ",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Cucumber cola",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mojito",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin mary",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "Virgin pinacolada",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "CORONA",
  "SellingPrice": 438
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRAFT BEERS",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA WHITE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA BLONDE 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIRA STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "KINGFISHER ULTRA MAX 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 330",
  "SellingPrice": 146
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER 650",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 330",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "BUDWIESER MAGNUM 650",
  "SellingPrice": 281
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 330",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "TUBORG STRONG 650",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "CRANBERRY ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "ORANGE",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMICAN",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE BERRY",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "MOET CHANDON",
  "SellingPrice": 7875
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA BRUT",
  "SellingPrice": 1687
}, {
  "Item Name": "MATEUS ROSE",
  "SellingPrice": 2137
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1890
}, {
  "Item Name": "HARDYS SIRAZ CABERNET BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 382
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1800
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACOB CREEK SIRAZ BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNIN BLANC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 990
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CHENNIN BLANC BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC 750 ",
  "SellingPrice": 1293
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA CHENIN BLANC BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC CHENNIN BLANC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1125
}, {
  "Item Name": "FOUR SEAZON CLASSIC CHENNIN BLANC BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINET SAUVIGNON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1125
}, {
  "Item Name": "BIG BANAYAN CARBINET SAUVIGNON BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1237
}, {
  "Item Name": "SULA SATORI MERLOT BY GLASS",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 1800
}, {
  "Item Name": "GROVERS LA RESERVE 100",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 700 ",
  "SellingPrice": 9225
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENFIDDICH 12 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 405
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 750",
  "SellingPrice": 8775
}, {
  "Item Name": "TALISKER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 750",
  "SellingPrice": 8887
}, {
  "Item Name": "GLENNLIVET 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 7942
}, {
  "Item Name": "THE SINGLETON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 750",
  "SellingPrice": 5062
}, {
  "Item Name": "AMRUT FUSION 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 7312
}, {
  "Item Name": "JACK DANIELS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4095
}, {
  "Item Name": "JIM BEAM WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4950
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAMESON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 8212
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 2925
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW BLACK LABEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 337
}, {
  "Item Name": "JW RED LABEL 200",
  "SellingPrice": 1158
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4545
}, {
  "Item Name": "BALLENTINSE FINEST BLENDED 30",
  "SellingPrice": 180
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 1575
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK \u0026 WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "100 PIPERS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 180",
  "SellingPrice": 675
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 60",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "VAT 69 30",
  "SellingPrice": 112
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 180",
  "SellingPrice": 787
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS HIGHLAND 30",
  "SellingPrice": 135
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 60",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "TEACHERS 50 30",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 1215
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG TRIPPLE GOLD 30",
  "SellingPrice": 213
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 731
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 247
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLACK DOG 8 YEARS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 123
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 2283
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 375",
  "SellingPrice": 1147
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 573
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLENDERS PRIDE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 450
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "SIGNATURE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 8190
}, {
  "Item Name": "GREY GOOSE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 326
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 700",
  "SellingPrice": 8122
}, {
  "Item Name": "BELVEDERE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 360
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 750",
  "SellingPrice": 7425
}, {
  "Item Name": "CIROC 30",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4556
}, {
  "Item Name": "ABSOLUT 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF RED30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMINOFF ORANGE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 551
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "SMIRNOFF GREEN APPLE30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4725
}, {
  "Item Name": "BOMBAY SAPHIRE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 750",
  "SellingPrice": 877
}, {
  "Item Name": "BLUE RIBBAND 60",
  "SellingPrice": 78
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 750",
  "SellingPrice": 2418
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI WHITE 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI ORANGE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 202
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI LEMON 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 393
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI BLACK 30",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD 180",
  "SellingPrice": 585
}, {
  "Item Name": "BACCARDI GOLD30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 180",
  "SellingPrice": 225
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "OLD MONK 30 ",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 750",
  "SellingPrice": 4668
}, {
  "Item Name": "DON ANGEL 30",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 700",
  "SellingPrice": 6153
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAUZA SILVER 30",
  "SellingPrice": 270
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERBOMB",
  "SellingPrice": 506
}, {
  "Item Name": "KAMAKAZI",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "JAGERMASTER",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "COINTTRAEU",
  "SellingPrice": 303
}, {
  "Item Name": "SAMBUCA",
  "SellingPrice": 258
}, {
  "Item Name": "KHALUA",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI BLANCO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MARTINI ROSSO",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 700",
  "SellingPrice": 7875
}, {
  "Item Name": "HENESSY VS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 348
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 750",
  "SellingPrice": 2182
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 180",
  "SellingPrice": 540
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 60",
  "SellingPrice": 191
}, {
  "Item Name": "MORPHEUS 30",
  "SellingPrice": 101
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 180",
  "SellingPrice": 292
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 90",
  "SellingPrice": 168
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "MC BRANDY 60",
  "SellingPrice": 90
}, {
  "Item Name": "RED BULL ",
  "SellingPrice": 157
}, {
  "Item Name": "COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SPRITE",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 33
}, {
  "Item Name": "DIET COKE",
  "SellingPrice": 56
}, {
  "Item Name": "TONIC WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "GINGER ALE",
  "SellingPrice": 67
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME SODA",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "LIME WATER",
  "SellingPrice": 45
}, {
  "Item Name": "PACKEGED WATER 1L",
  "SellingPrice": 39
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}, {
  "Item Name": "MANSION HOUSE 650",
  "SellingPrice": 900
}, {
  "Item Name": "Chole Kulche",
  "SellingPrice": 80
}, {
  "Item Name": "Butter Nan",
  "SellingPrice": 65
}, {
  "Item Name": "Dhai",
  "SellingPrice": 20
}, {
  "Item Name": "Rice",
  "SellingPrice": 55
}, {
  "Item Name": "Plain rice",
  "SellingPrice": 30
}]

myFun();
window.setInterval(showRows, 5000);
showRows();

function myFun() {
  addTable(tableValue);
}

function showRows() {
  $(".hidden:lt(10)").removeClass("hidden");
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table"
    }),

    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {
      class: "hidden"
    });
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {

        $("<td/>", {
          "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
        }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable">
</div>
```

**Edit**
I have tried @Void's solution but that is not removing the `hidden` class,when I inspect the element then there is no class applied to `tr` it is showing as `class=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to extract portion of the array and render that into html:

```js
//source data sample
const tableValue=[{"Item Name":"MANCHOW  V SOUP","SellingPrice":100},{"Item Name":"MANCHOW NV SOUP ","SellingPrice":125},{"Item Name":"CEASER SALAD V","SellingPrice":175},{"Item Name":"CEASER SALAD NV","SellingPrice":230},{"Item Name":"GAMBUS REBOZADAS","SellingPrice":350},{"Item Name":"PANCO FISH FINGER","SellingPrice":270},{"Item Name":"MUSHROOM DUPLEX","SellingPrice":160},{"Item Name":"FRENCH FRIES","SellingPrice":99},{"Item Name":"HONEY GARLIC PRAWN","SellingPrice":350},{"Item Name":"CHICKEN MANCHURIAN","SellingPrice":180},{"Item Name":"MUSHROOM CHILLY","SellingPrice":120},{"Item Name":"SALT N PEPPER BABY CORN","SellingPrice":120},{"Item Name":"SOUTHERN STYLE CHICKEN","SellingPrice":210},{"Item Name":"PANEER NAGGETS","SellingPrice":210},{"Item Name":"HARA BHARA KEBAB","SellingPrice":160},{"Item Name":"CHICKEN TIKKA","SellingPrice":210},{"Item Name":"KALMI KEBAB","SellingPrice":250},{"Item Name":"PIZZA MARGARITTA","SellingPrice":200},{"Item Name":"PIZZA VEG FARMHOUSE","SellingPrice":200},{"Item Name":"BBQ CHICKEN PIZZA","SellingPrice":225},{"Item Name":"CHICKEN TIKKA PIZZA","SellingPrice":225},{"Item Name":"PESTO SAUCE","SellingPrice":175},{"Item Name":"ARABIATA","SellingPrice":160},{"Item Name":"PINK SAUCE","SellingPrice":160},{"Item Name":"GARBANZO BEAN SALAD","SellingPrice":90},{"Item Name":"MASALA PAPAD","SellingPrice":50},{"Item Name":"PEANUT MASALA","SellingPrice":60},{"Item Name":"GAJAR KA HALWA","SellingPrice":90},{"Item Name":"WATERMELON MARTINI","SellingPrice":281.25},{"Item Name":"Kiwi martini","SellingPrice":281.25},{"Item Name":" Apple gin","SellingPrice":225}];

//calculate the number of "pages" with 20 items per page
const rounds = Math.ceil(tableValue.length/20);
//initialize page counter
var round = 1;
//render array of objects into table HTML, based on
//the source data and index (first item on the "page")
const renderTable = (arr, index) => {
  //chop off 20 items starting from "page" counter
  //multiplied by 20
  arr = arr.slice(index*20, index*20+20);
  //break 20 items into array of chunks by 4 items (per row)
  const chunkedArr = arr.reduceRight((res,_,__,self) => [...res, self.splice(0, 4)],[]);
  //map each chunk of 4 items into <tr> code, 
  //reducing each object into pair of <td> nodes 
  //(name, price) and join resulting array of <tr> codes
  return chunkedArr.map(tr => `<tr>${tr.reduce((rowhtml, td) => rowhtml += `<td class="text-left">${td['Item Name']}</td><td class="text-right">${td['SellingPrice']}</td>`, '')}</tr>`).join('');
};
//render initial portion of source data
$('#DisplayTable').html(renderTable(tableValue, 0));
//repeat rendering each 3 seconds, reset counter on the last "page"
const rotateTable = window.setInterval(() => {
   $('#DisplayTable').html(renderTable(tableValue, round));
   if(round == rounds-1) round = 0;
   else round++;
}, 3000);
```

```css
td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
td:nth-child(1),td:nth-child(2) {
  background: #4AD184;
}
td:nth-child(3),td:nth-child(4) {
  background: #EA69EF;
}
td:nth-child(5),td:nth-child(6){
  background: #E1A558;
}
td:nth-child(7),td:nth-child(8) {
  background: #F4F065;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<table class="table" id="DisplayTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Only one column is displaying, i have done it for 4 columns

Comment: Those selling price are aligning  with name i have right aligned them in my code, i tried to edit in your code but you are appending both in one go

Comment: Your table rendering code is very complex, that's why i am finding hard to do some changes from my side

Comment: yup, i also got that, I wanted to ask one doubt where are you calculating to show 5 rows in my real code i have to show different no of rows,

Comment: @manishthakur : I have appended my comments to the code. I don't actually count 5 rows. I break 20 items that fall onto each "page" into groups by 4 items each so there are naturally formed **5** groups.

Comment: @manishthakur : You might notice I iterate twice over those target 20 items. I have done that deliberately to have that piece of code (breaking array into groups of fixed size) reusable.

Comment: hey sir can you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521258/how-to-display-image-dynamically-on-ui with some approach

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating the rows after every 5 seconds, you can create the rows in one go and hide them all using a class `.hidden`. Then every 5 seconds make first 5 hidden rows visible.

```
$(".hidden:lt(5)").removeClass("hidden");
```

Call this every 5 seconds.

```js
var tableValue = [{
    "Item Name": "MANCHOW  V SOUP",
    "SellingPrice": 100
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "MANCHOW NV SOUP ",
    "SellingPrice": 125
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD V",
    "SellingPrice": 175
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CEASER SALAD NV",
    "SellingPrice": 230
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "GAMBUS REBOZADAS",
    "SellingPrice": 350
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PANCO FISH FINGER",
    "SellingPrice": 270
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "MUSHROOM DUPLEX",
    "SellingPrice": 160
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "FRENCH FRIES",
    "SellingPrice": 99
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "HONEY GARLIC PRAWN",
    "SellingPrice": 350
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CHICKEN MANCHURIAN",
    "SellingPrice": 180
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "MUSHROOM CHILLY",
    "SellingPrice": 120
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "SALT N PEPPER BABY CORN",
    "SellingPrice": 120
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "SOUTHERN STYLE CHICKEN",
    "SellingPrice": 210
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PANEER NAGGETS",
    "SellingPrice": 210
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "HARA BHARA KEBAB",
    "SellingPrice": 160
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA",
    "SellingPrice": 210
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "KALMI KEBAB",
    "SellingPrice": 250
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PIZZA MARGARITTA",
    "SellingPrice": 200
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PIZZA VEG FARMHOUSE",
    "SellingPrice": 200
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "BBQ CHICKEN PIZZA",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CHICKEN TIKKA PIZZA",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PESTO SAUCE",
    "SellingPrice": 175
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "ARABIATA",
    "SellingPrice": 160
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PINK SAUCE",
    "SellingPrice": 160
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "GARBANZO BEAN SALAD",
    "SellingPrice": 90
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "MASALA PAPAD",
    "SellingPrice": 50
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "PEANUT MASALA",
    "SellingPrice": 60
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "GAJAR KA HALWA",
    "SellingPrice": 90
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "WATERMELON MARTINI",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Kiwi martini",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": " Apple gin",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Cucumber  cooler ",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Martini",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Pink lady",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": " Bloody marry",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Cosmopolitan",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Sex on the beach",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Bull frog",
    "SellingPrice": 506.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Long  island iced tea ",
    "SellingPrice": 393.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Pinacolada",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Daiquiri",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Mojito ",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Whisky sour",
    "SellingPrice": 281.25
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Hot toddy",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Margarita",
    "SellingPrice": 337.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Tequila sunrise",
    "SellingPrice": 337.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Red sangria",
    "SellingPrice": 225
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "White sangria",
    "SellingPrice": 247.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Rose sangria",
    "SellingPrice": 247.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "By chance special ",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Made in heaven",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Strawberry delight",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "DRAGON",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Mangochil ",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Cucumber cola",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Virgin mojito",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Virgin mary",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "Virgin pinacolada",
    "SellingPrice": 168.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CORONA",
    "SellingPrice": 438.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "CRAFT BEERS",
    "SellingPrice": 337.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "BIRA WHITE 330",
    "SellingPrice": 157.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "BIRA BLONDE 330",
    "SellingPrice": 135
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "BIRA STRONG 650",
    "SellingPrice": 213.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 330",
    "SellingPrice": 123.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 650",
    "SellingPrice": 202.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 330",
    "SellingPrice": 123.75
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "KINGFISHER PREMIUM 650",
    "SellingPrice": 202.5
  },
  {
    "Item Name": "TESTING ITEM",
    "SellingPrice": 22
  }
]

myFun();
window.setInterval(showRows, 5000);
showRows();
function myFun() {
  addTable(tableValue);
}

function showRows(){
  $(".hidden:lt(5)").removeClass("hidden");
}

function addTable(tableValue) {
  var $tbl = $("<table />", {
      "class": "table"
    }),

    $tb = $("<tbody/>"),
    $trh = $("<tr/>");

  var split = Math.round(tableValue.length / 4);
  for (i = 0; i < split; i++) {
    $tr = $("<tr/>", {class: "hidden"});
    for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      $.each(tableValue[split * j + i], function(key, value) {

        $("<td/>", {
          "class": "text-left color" + (j + 1)
        }).html(value).appendTo($tr);
      });
    }
    $tr.appendTo($tb);
  }
  $tbl.append($tb);
  $("#DisplayTable").html($tbl);
}
```

```css
tbody>tr>td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 8pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.color1 {
  background: #4AD184;
}

.color2 {
  background: #EA69EF;
}

.color3 {
  background: #E1A558;
}

.color4 {
  background: #F4F065;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="DisplayTable">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create empty HTML table with 4 rows and give unique ID to each field "field0", "field1"...

Than you can make function to populate those field after specific time. At the end it would look something like this:

```
var data = [
    {
        name: "test data 0"
    },
    {
        name: "test data 1"
    }
]; //Your data
var currentField = 0; //Current offset for the field

$(function() { //When document loads
    showNext(); //Populate first 4 fields
    setInterval(showNext, 4000); //Set up "timer" to populate new ones on every 4 seconds
});

function showNext(){
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        $("#column" + i + " #field0").text = data[i + currentField].name;
        $("#column" + i + " #field1").text = data[i + currentField].price;
        currentField++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't get you can you make a working code with my existing code

Comment: Point is to give you idea how to solve problem, not to write you complete solution.

Comment: yup, but i didn't get any idea from this

Comment: Idea is to already have HTML table in which you are just going to swap values instead creating new table every time you want to swap values.